# Disappear the view(RelativeLayout,LinearLayout,or any view) while clicking or tapping outside its boundries?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Do anyone know this how to do it without using transparent views beneath the view which i want to disappear?

Comment: Design the view to be disappear as a child view and try making it invisible on the onclick listener of the parent view.

Comment: Thanx but i don't need this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a layout like this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/abs__progress_medium_holo"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In you code add,

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);

    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            img.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    });
```

Or try this,

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
   { 
      imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
   } 
       return true; 
}
```

Comment: Thanx but i know these solution. but i don't want this.

Comment: Then what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: i actually wanna know whether the views have some methods to detect the tap is done outside it or not. As dialogs have method "Dialog object.setCancelWhentTouchOutside(boolean)".

Comment: Have you tried this??, public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{  

       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  

             imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }  
       return true;  
}

Comment: No i dint tried this thanks let me try it once. after some minutes i'll tell you the status brothaaa.